# How to apply call read function in if-else or ternary operator construction in Karate framework

Tags: karate, karate-call-single

How to use conditions if-else  or ternary operator in Karate framework and determine ether feature file will continue execute a current script or break(stop) with a specified message?

I have tried a following script:
At the begining of the scenario I need to start with that condition:

@maintest
And def currentTime
And def closingTime
And def result = (currentTime < closingTime) ? call read(...@maintest) : break (and print "Store is closed)
Given ....
And ...

So my goal to continue the execution is condition is true and stop the execution with appropriate print message if it false. Thank you.

Comment: also refer: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#call-vs-read